# Jenkins Service to redirect http:servername:8080 to https:servername:8080

Tags: http, jenkins, https

We used http:servername:8080 when configured jenkins. Later we enabled ssl and made the jenkins access under https:servername:8080. But We want to redirect http:servername:8080 to https:servername:8080. Can you please help us here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change the port for https connections, because the server can not listen on the same port for the same protocol (in your case TCP protocol and port 8080).

For example, you can configure **https** to a default **443** port.

Regarding redirection, actually, it is recommended to put a **reverse proxy** in front of the jenkins server. See official documentation about running jenkins with SSL https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=135468777.

Here is the manual how to configure jenkins behind an nginx reverse proxy with http to https redirection: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy